# Extending polyfit line in MatLab

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to extend my polyfit line of best fit in Matlab. I want it to extend to y = 200 and x = 64. What would be the best way of doing this?

Cheers Tom

[Link to image of polyfit through data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDBCZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Plot your `polyval` over a different range. Something like that should work:

```
% Make up data
x = 1:100;
y = -0.03.*x.^2 + 2*x + 10*randn(size(x));
x2 = -50:150;

P = polyfit(x,y,2);

plot(x,y,'o',x2,polyval(P,x2),'--');
grid on;
```

Comment: I dont know x2 because I'm trying to fit a straight line to a zig-zag line.

Comment: @MelB can you ellaborate? I've used `x2` just to get a smoother plot and show that the fit can be evaluated anywhere, not only at the values of x. In the code above one could as well write: `plot(x,y,'o',x,polyval(P,x),'--');` instead.